# jQuery slice to return an array?

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to get jQuery slice to return an array of elements instead of a jQuery object?  Perhaps an alternative function from a jQuery compatible library?

Or do I have to covert into an array myself using [makeArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/) (or doing it myself)?

(I ask because once I discovered [each2](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-misc-plugins/), I am always imagining there is a slightly more optimized function out there for a given task).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.get()` to return an "normal" array from a jQuery object.

Example:

```
var arr = $('div').slice(2, 4).get();
```

Comment: `.toArray()` should actually be a little faster, since that's what `.get()` with no arguments calls.